# Let virtual method accept any Qt container type as input paramter

Tags: c++, qt, containers

I have two graph classes: `DirectedGraph` and `DirectedBreakableGraph`. `DirectedBreakableGraph` inherits from `DirectedGraph`, and provides the ability to temporarily *break* edges, meaning that they should not be traversed, even though they are still part of the graph. This way cycles in the graph can temporarily be resolved.

`DirectedGraph` has a `DFS` (depth-first search) method for traversing the graph. This method is `virtual`, so that `DirectedBreakableGraph` can have its own implementation, ignoring broken edges.

I want to be able to specify from which node(s) the depth-first search should start, by passing a collection of start nodes to `DFS`. Now, I do not want to put restrictions on the type of the collection containing the start nodes. It could for example be a `QVector` or a `QSet`.

Since the method is virtual, it cannot also be a template. Is it then impossible to let it accept both `QVector` and `QSet` as input parameter? Maybe apart from using [type erasure](https://www.artima.com/articles/on-the-tension-between-object-oriented-and-generic-programming-in-c)?

```
class DirectedGraph {
public:
    // DFS should accept either QVector or QSet.
    virtual void DFS(QVector<Node *> const &StartNodes) const;
};

class DirectedBreakableGraph : public DirectedGraph {
public:
    // DFS should accept either QVector or QSet.
    void DFS(QVector<Node *> const &StartNodes) const override;
};
```

Comment: No, it's not impossible. Try an `std::variant` or equivalent, for example.

Comment: Is it impossible to use template here? All those containers are iterable, you could have iteration traits and pass that to your virtual method. Those traits would then be templated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With type erasure, you might do something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct IGenerator
{
    virtual ~IGenerator() = default;
    virtual void reset() = 0;
    virtual const T* value_and_next() = 0;
};

template <typename Container>
struct Generator : IGenerator<typename Container::value_type>
{
    Generator(const Container& container) : container(container), it(container.begin()) {}
    virtual void reset() override { it = container.begin(); }
    virtual const typename Container::value_type* value_and_next() override
    {
        if (it == container) { return nullptr; }
        return &(*it++);
    }

    const Container& container;
    typename Container::const_iterator it;
};


class DirectedGraph {
public:
    // DFS should accept either QVector or QSet.
    virtual void DFS(IGenerator<Node *> const &StartNodes) const
    {
        while (const auto* p = StartNodes.value_and_next()) {
            Node* node = *p;
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

and then you might do

```
directGraph.DFS(Generator{myVector});
directGraph.DFS(Generator{mySet});
```